# Importing two FragmentManager types into the same class

Tags: java, android, fragmentmanager

In a single activity, I am trying to combine a ViewPager and a BottomNavigationView. I am using a [third party library](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) for the BottomNavigationView (**AHBottomNavigation**). Now, here's the problem:

While trying to use a FragmentManager, the Viewpager requires `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` but the BottomNavigationView requires `android.app.FragmentManager`. Since both classes cannot be imported at the same time, I am at crossroads as to what to do next.

**PS:**    A quick solution to this problem would be to find a more compatible library. However, in my case, it is very expensive to switch libraries, what can I do?

Comment: `android.app.FragmentManager` is deprecated and should not be used. You should request that the library developer switch over to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since both classes cannot be imported at the same time, I am at crossroads as to what to do next.

You don't need to import them both at the same time - you can use each class's fully qualified name.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager supportManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentManager oldAssManager = getFragmentManager();
```

---

P.S. - I would highly encourage you to ditch a 3rd party library that is still using the old fragment manager, especially for a `BottomNavigationView` when [an official one already exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView).

P.P.S - Per the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior) (scroll down to "Transition"), you should not do a "swipe" animation to switch between tabs, which is what a `ViewPager` does by default, so you may also want to rethink combining those two components.

Hope that helps!